# Windows Store 8.1: WebView.NavigateToStream does not work when altering stream

Tags: xaml, webview, windows-store-apps, c#-5.0, windows-8.1

I am currently trying to use the WebView to display encrypted data (using DPP). The issue is that I am not able to get the WebView to show anything if the stream is manipulated in any way after reading the StorageFile into an IRandomAccessStream (ie. unencrypt the data).

This issue can easily be reproduced by using the source provided by Microsoft: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-WebView-control-sample-58ad63f7

and altering the "StreamUriWinRTResolver" class to convert the IRandomAccessStream to a memory stream and then back again. Basically, in S4_NavToStream.xaml.cs at line 128, change this:

```
StorageFile f = item as StorageFile;
IRandomAccessStream stream = await f.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
return stream.GetInputStreamAt(0);
```

With this:

```
StorageFile f = item as StorageFile;
IRandomAccessStream randStream = await f.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
var stream = randStream.AsStream();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
stream.CopyTo(ms);
return ms.AsInputStream();
```

This will show a blank page when run. I'm starting to think this is a bug, unless of course I'm using the stream conversions incorrectly. Has anybody tried anything similar?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? Is the text copied to the `MemoryStream` correctly?

Comment: Yes. The size of the memory stream is correct, although I did not compare byte for byte. In my actual application, I copied the unencrypted stream to disk before passing the stream to the webview, and the correct html file was generated on disk -- yet it showed a blank page in the webview :(

Answer (score 0):

Thomas Huber has very graciously answered my question over on social.msdn.microsoft.com. Full answer here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f51ab699-66c3-4961-8952-fbe341bf3e23/windows-81-webviewnavigatetostream-does-not-work-when-altering-the-stream

In summary, the issue is around the conversion of the memory stream to an input stream. This is the correct working code:

```
StorageFile f = item as StorageFile;
IRandomAccessStream randStream = await f.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
var stream = randStream.AsStream();
var ms = new MemoryStream();
stream.CopyTo(ms);

InMemoryRandomAccessStream msras = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
DataWriter dw = new DataWriter(msras);
dw.WriteBytes(ms.ToArray());
await dw.StoreAsync();
var inputStream= msras.GetInputStreamAt(0);
return inputStream;
```